# What are the pitfalls of having a two dlls share a static library?

Tags: c++, windows, dll

Say you have two dlls

Dll A and Dll B

They both statically link to a static library (ie a .lib file). We'll call that library L.

I know that L fully links into A and B separately effectively creating LA and LB. However, what happens when object O from LA gets passed from A to B? I assume in A LA code gets executed while in B LB code gets executed because thats how linking happened. What bad things can happen if you create O in A, unload A, then use O in B?

Comment: When you unload A, the code for object O has gone. Attempting to call methods on O will result  in runtime errors.

Comment: @David, is that true? Or is O when existing in dll B using LB code?

Comment: You created OA and then unloaded the code behind it. That always ends in tears.

Comment: @David, I'm not sure. When you refer methods of O in B, LB exists to satisfy the linker for those methods. The linker resolves O::foo() calls to LB's O::foo's code and fully links it. It doesn't care that O actually came from LA AFAIK.

Comment: @David: It does not strictly have to, particularly if `O` is a POD object. But it is a really, _really_ bad idea to do that.

Comment: @Nicol I'm assuming O is a class and it's the method calls that are the problem.

Comment: @David: Well, you're lucky if it results in runtime errors. You're unlucky if it results in remote code execution vulnerabilities :)

Comment: @Doug: the linker won't necessarily be involved in resolving a call to O::foo.  Object O may contain a pointer to a table of functions, in order to support polymorphism, or other pointers to data that won't be there any more once LA is unloaded.  (For that matter, depending on context, LA might have released the memory block that O itself is stored in!)

Answer (score 5):

A static library is just a collection of object files. When you link with a static library, everything happens as if the code of the static library had been included into yours.

So if there are global variables in the static library, each DLL will get its own copy, which may or may not be what you want.

Comment: This can be really surprising when you try to create a singleton.

Comment: That's probably the most obvious consequence, but I wonder if you could expand -- What happens to virtual functions? Which code gets called on object O when in A or B? What exactly happens in those cases?

Answer (score 2):

> However, what happens when object O from LA gets passed from A to B?

It really depends on what object `O` is and what the library `L` does with it. If `O` is an object that is entirely dependent on state stored within that object, then everything will probably be fine. However, if `O` is not, if `O` depends on global state or the state of some other object or something, you could have problems.

The best way to avoid problems is to have proper layers of insulation between two DLLs. That is, you shouldn't be passing `O` between the two at all, since they're not talking about the same `O`. In general, if `L` is big enough to require you to pass its objects between two users, then it is big enough that you probably should consider dynamically linking to it.